# High voltage supply

Tags: voltage, converter

I need to power a high voltage amplifier circuit at 400 V. I expect the circuit to draw a maximum of 50 mA, so around 20 W. My idea was to use a DC-DC converter from say 12V to the 450 V that I need, but I can not find any compact commercially available source with these characteristics. What is the best way to do so? Any advice?

Comment: Why convert 12 V to 450 V. Where does the 12 V come from? If you have mains voltage available it might be easier to just buy a power supply than outputs 400 V DC. Don't ask "What is the best way..." because "the best" is very dependent on what you need. In the middle of the desert solar panels and a battery might work best. When mains voltage is available, it will be cheaper to use that.

Comment: The best way is probably to look harder and longer or, build one yourself.

Comment: Emco manufactures such things, if you have the coin, and wish to avoid making your own.

Answer (score 0):

The LT3751 is used in this type of application: -

[image]

It can supply up to 100 mA load current if you [read the data sheet on pg 26](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3751.pdf): -

[image]

You may also be able to buy modules using it. Use LT3751 as a key word. You might get lucky.

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{Be aware - it could kill you if not handled correctly}}}$$